# Capture Opened Workbook in New Instance of Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of macros where I want it run some code, then prompt the user to export an Excel workbook from another program, then run more code once the export has been opened. The tricky part is that some programs export to a new instance of Excel, while other programs export to the current instance.

The current workflow is (code at bottom):

1. Call the central 'Capture' Module with the name of the export (some
   programs export 'Book[x]' some do 'workbook[x]', etc.) and the
   procedure you want to run once the export is found.
2. Capture Module gets a list of all existing workbook names from all
   Excel instances and saves as a Module-level string.
3. Capture Module uses Application.OnTime so that every 3 seconds, it
   scans the list of all workbooks across all Excel instances.
4. If it finds a workbook that is not in the previously saved list of
   all existing workbook names, and that contains the name of the
   export, it stores that workbook as a public module level variable,
   and runs the saved procedure from Step 1, which can the reference
   the store workbook.

This works very well in all circumstances, *EXCEPT* for one. If I already have Book1.xlsx open in my current instance of Excel, and the 3rd party program exports Book1.xlsx to a NEW instance of Excel, the program doesn't recognize this as the export, since Book1.xlsx is in the existing workbook names string array already.

My solution is to find some way of uniquely identifying each workbook that's better than 'Name' or 'Path'. I tried saving each workbook name in the existing workbook names string as [application.hwnd]![workbook name] but this was an unstable fix and frequently broke (I don't really understand how hwnd works so I can't say why).

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Sample Procedures That Use MCaptureExport**

```
Public Sub GrabFXAllExport()

    Const sSOURCE As String = "GrabFXAllExport"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If Not TAAA.MCaptureExport.bCaptureExport("FXALL", "TAAA.FXAllEmail.ProcessFXAllExport") Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

ErrorExit:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE, , True) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub ProcessFXAllExport()

    Const sSOURCE As String = "ProcessFXAllExport"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If MCaptureExport.mwbCaptured Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Exported Workbook Not Found. Please try again.", vbCritical, gsAPP_NAME
        GoTo ErrorExit
    End If

    Dim wsSourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set wsSourceSheet = MCaptureExport.mwbCaptured.Worksheets(1)
    Set MCaptureExport.mwbCaptured = Nothing

    [I now have the export and can work with it as a I please]

ErrorExit:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE, , True) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Sub
```

**MCaptureExport Module**

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

' Description:  This module contains the central error
'               handler and related constant declarations.
Private Const msMODULE As String = "MCaptureExport"

Private sExistingWorkbookList() As String
Public mwbCaptured As Workbook
Public msCaptureType As String
Private sReturnProcedure As String
Private bListening As Boolean
Public Function bCaptureExport(sCaptureType As String, sRunAfterCapture As String) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bCaptureExport()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    If Not bWorkbookNamesAsArray(sExistingWorkbookList, True, False) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

    sReturnProcedure = sRunAfterCapture
    bListening = True
    msCaptureType = sCaptureType
    TAAA.MCaptureExport.WaitForCapture sCaptureTypeToNameContains(msCaptureType)
    MsgBox "Waiting for " & msCaptureType & " Export", vbInformation, gsAPP_NAME

ErrorExit:

    bCaptureExport = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function

Private Sub WaitForCapture(sNameContains As String)

    Const sSOURCE As String = "WaitForCapture"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim wbCaptureCheck As Workbook
    If Not bCaptureCheck(sNameContains, wbCaptureCheck) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

    If wbCaptureCheck Is Nothing Then
        If bListening Then _
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3), "'TAAA.MCaptureExport.WaitForCapture " & Chr(34) & sNameContains & Chr(34) & "'"
    Else
        Dim bSameApp As Boolean
        If Not bWorkbooksInSameApp(ThisWorkbook, wbCaptureCheck, bSameApp) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

        If Not bSameApp Then
            Dim sTempFilePath As String
            sTempFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_" & Format(Now, "mmddyyhhmmss") & ".xls"
            wbCaptureCheck.SaveCopyAs sTempFilePath
            wbCaptureCheck.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set wbCaptureCheck = Application.Workbooks.Open(sTempFilePath)
        End If

        Set mwbCaptured = wbCaptureCheck
        bListening = False
        Application.Run sReturnProcedure
    End If

ErrorExit:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE, , True) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Sub
Private Function sCaptureTypeToNameContains(sCaptureType As String) As String

    sCaptureTypeToNameContains = "*"

    On Error Resume Next

    Select Case UCase(sCaptureType)
        Case "SOTER": sCaptureTypeToNameContains = "workbook"
        Case "THOR": sCaptureTypeToNameContains = "Book"
        Case "FXALL": sCaptureTypeToNameContains = "search_results_export"
    End Select

End Function
Private Function bCaptureCheck(sNameContains As String, wbResult As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bCaptureCheck()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim xlApps() As Application
    If Not bGetAllExcelInstances(xlApps) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        For Each wb In xlApps(i).Workbooks

            If wb.Name Like "*" & sNameContains & "*" _
                And Not bIsInArray(wb.Name, sExistingWorkbookList) Then

                Set wbResult = wb
                GoTo ErrorExit

            End If
        Next
    Next

ErrorExit:

    bCaptureCheck = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function
```

**Utility Functions Used by MCaptureExport**

```
Public Function bWorkbookNamesAsArray(sResult() As String, Optional bAllInstances As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bWorkbookNamesAsArray()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim xlApps() As Application

    Dim ResultArray() As String
    Dim Ndx As Integer, wbCount As Integer

    If bAllInstances Then
        If Not bGetAllExcelInstances(xlApps) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
    Else
        ReDim xlApps(0)
        Set xlApps(0) = Application
    End If

    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        For Each wb In xlApps(i).Workbooks
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
        Next
    Next

    ReDim ResultArray(1 To wbCount)

    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        For Each wb In xlApps(i).Workbooks
            Ndx = Ndx + 1
            ResultArray(Ndx) = wb.Name
        Next
    Next

    sResult = ResultArray()

ErrorExit:

    bWorkbookNamesAsArray = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Public Function bGetAllExcelInstances(xlApps() As Application) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bGetAllExcelInstances()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim n As Long

    Dim hWndMain As LongPtr

    Dim app As Application

    ' Cater for 100 potential Excel instances, clearly could be better
    ReDim xlApps(1 To 100)

    hWndMain = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)

    Do While hWndMain <> 0
        If Not bGetExcelObjectFromHwnd(hWndMain, app) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

        If Not (app Is Nothing) Then
            If n = 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                Set xlApps(n) = app
            ElseIf bCheckHwnds(xlApps, app.Hwnd) Then
                n = n + 1
                Set xlApps(n) = app
            End If
        End If
        hWndMain = FindWindowEx(0&, hWndMain, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)

    Loop

    If n Then
        ReDim Preserve xlApps(1 To n)
        'GetAllExcelInstances = n
    Else
        Erase xlApps
    End If

ErrorExit:

    bGetAllExcelInstances = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function


Private Function bCheckHwnds(xlApps() As Application, Hwnd As LongPtr) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        If Not xlApps(i) Is Nothing Then
            If xlApps(i).Hwnd = Hwnd Then
                bCheckHwnds = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    bCheckHwnds = True

End Function
Public Function bWorkbooksInSameApp(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, bSameApp As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bWorkbooksInSameApp()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    bSameApp = wb1.Application.Hwnd = wb2.Application.Hwnd

ErrorExit:

    bWorkbooksInSameApp = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bGetExcelObjectFromHwnd(ByVal hWndMain As LongPtr, aAppResult As Application) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bGetExcelObjectFromHwnd()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim hWndDesk As LongPtr
    Dim Hwnd As LongPtr
    Dim strText As String
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim iid As UUID
    Dim obj As Object

    hWndDesk = FindWindowEx(hWndMain, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)

    If hWndDesk <> 0 Then

        Hwnd = FindWindowEx(hWndDesk, 0, vbNullString, vbNullString)

        Do While Hwnd <> 0

        strText = String$(100, Chr$(0))
        lngRet = CLng(GetClassName(Hwnd, strText, 100))

        If Left$(strText, lngRet) = "EXCEL7" Then

            Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)

            If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(Hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = 0 Then 'S_OK

                Set aAppResult = obj.Application
                GoTo ErrorExit

            End If

        End If

        Hwnd = FindWindowEx(hWndDesk, Hwnd, vbNullString, vbNullString)
        Loop

    End If

ErrorExit:

    bGetExcelObjectFromHwnd = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Tough to handle out-of-process stuff like this, is there a way instead you can prompt the user to export/save-as the output Excel file? Then you simply need a FileDialog and prompt the user to select the (exported) file from the other application.

Comment: One idea that should work is, instead of cacheing the list of open workbook names, assign to each workbook a `CustomDocumentProperty`  that you can reasonably ensure will not exist in the exported XLSX files. Then, you can simply scan the applications/workbooks for the file (by name) which **does not have this property**.

Comment: @DavidZemens That's an interesting idea! If my solution below with hWnd doesn't working, I'm going to try yours next. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: That seems like it ought to work...

Comment: You could also compare the `ObjPtr` values of the several workbooks with the same name.

Comment: @DavidZemens I encountered some problems with hWnd and ended up using your CustomDocumentProperty method. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure you clear out that property when you close out of the workbook(s) -- or, find a way to ensure you're using a *unique* property at each session's runtime.

Comment: @DavidZemens Great point, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a potential solution. However I want to leave the question open. This is a fairly complicated problem and I bet there are more elegant solutions than what I'm proposing.

So I updated the format of sExistingWorkbookList to [Application.hWnd]![Workbook.name]. I had tried this before but I think it's working this time.

Thoughts?

**Updated Version of bWorkbookNamesAsArray**

Added `wb.Application.Hwnd & "!" &` to `ResultArray(Ndx) = wb.name`

```
Public Function bWorkbookNamesAsArray(sResult() As String, Optional bAllInstances As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bWorkbookNamesAsArray()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim xlApps() As Application

    Dim ResultArray() As String
    Dim Ndx As Integer, wbCount As Integer

    If bAllInstances Then
        If Not bGetAllExcelInstances(xlApps) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
    Else
        ReDim xlApps(0)
        Set xlApps(0) = Application
    End If

    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        For Each wb In xlApps(i).Workbooks
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
        Next
    Next

    ReDim ResultArray(1 To wbCount)

    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        For Each wb In xlApps(i).Workbooks
            Ndx = Ndx + 1
            ResultArray(Ndx) = wb.Application.Hwnd & "!" & wb.Name
        Next
    Next

    sResult = ResultArray()

ErrorExit:

    bWorkbookNamesAsArray = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
```

**New Utility Function**

```
Public Function bGetWorkbookFromHwndAndName(ByVal sWorkbookReference As String, ByRef wbResult As Workbook)

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bGetWorkbookFromHwndAndName()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim xlApp As Application

    If Not bGetExcelObjectFromHwnd(CLng(Split(sWorkbookReference, "!")(0)), xlApp) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

    Set wbResult = xlApp.Workbooks(Split(sWorkbookReference, "!")(1))

ErrorExit:

    bGetWorkbookFromHwndAndName = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function
```

**Updated MCaptureExport.bCaptureCheck()**

```
    Private Function bCaptureCheck(sNameContains As String, wbResult As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSOURCE As String = "bCaptureCheck()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook, sFullWorkbookReference As String
    Dim xlApps() As Application
    If Not bGetAllExcelInstances(xlApps) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
    For i = LBound(xlApps) To UBound(xlApps)
        For Each wb In xlApps(i).Workbooks

            sFullWorkbookReference = wb.Application.Hwnd & "!" & wb.Name

            If wb.Name Like "*" & sNameContains & "*" _
                And Not bIsInArray(sFullWorkbookReference, sExistingWorkbookList) Then

                If Not bGetWorkbookFromHwndAndName(sFullWorkbookReference, wbResult) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
                GoTo ErrorExit

            End If
        Next
    Next

ErrorExit:

    bCaptureCheck = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function
```